# SolidColorBrush color change at runtime

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0

I have in my application resources file brush:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainColor" Color="#FF15428B" />
```

I want to change color of this brush at runtime. I added color picker - when user choose color I want this brush to have selected color.

I tried code like that:

```
SolidColorBrush MainColor = new SolidColorBrush(SelectedColor);
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the **existing** brush's `Color` property.

You can get the instance by writing `(SolidColorBrush)Resources["MainColor"]`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked :). I used code: Application.Current.Resources["MainColor"] = new SolidColorBrush(SelectedColor);

Answer (score 3):

You can access Resources from the code-behind with the TryFindResource method:

```
SolidColorBrush myBrush = (SolidColorBrush)this.TryFindResource("myBrush");

if (myBrush != null)
{
    myBrush.Color = Colors.Yellow  ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
MainColor = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(
    SelectedColor.A, SelectedColor.R, SelectedColor.G, SelectedColor.B
));
```