# changing color at run time but hits with exception

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I have defined a custom SolidColorBrush in my app.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>       
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="App_DarkForeground" Color="White"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

in my page1.xaml, i am using above brush as

```
<TextBlock x:Name="lblTileColor" Text="user color:" Foreground="{StaticResource App_DarkForeground}"/>
```

I am trying to change the color of this brush at run time based on user event in c#.

I am using below piece to set the color but i am hitting with this exception.

```
Application.Current.Resources["App_DarkForeground"] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xff, 255, 122, 255));
```

Here is the exception details:

```
 An exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
```

i followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266674/solidcolorbrush-color-change-at-runtime) but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you linked was talking about how its done in WPF not windows phone. Apparently, for windows phone you cannot set resource dictionary values.

Why not just assign the foreground property in code?

```cs
lblTileColor.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xff, 255, 122, 255));
```

Or if you are using MVVM you can just bind it:

```xml
<TextBlock x:Name="lblTileColor" Text="user color:" Foreground="{Binding ForegroundProperty"} />
```

Comment: got it, your suggestion is good for changing 1 or 2 controls foreground color...how about in page there are over 15 controls where i wanted to apply this brush.

Comment: In this case the only solution I can think of is through MVVM and binding the Foreground property of all the 15 controls to the same property in your view model.

Comment: Sorry for asking more, i am new to MVVM...in my xaml i defined 3 text blocks with --- Foreground="{Binding ForegroundProperty"} --- binding...in my code behind,i have ---- public SolidColorBrush ForegroundProperty { get; set; } ---- and on user event i am changing the value of this brush to -----                 ForegroundProperty = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xff, 255, 255, 255)); ------ but somehow my change is not reflecting when the event occurs, UI is not updating with new color.

Comment: You need to create a separate class for your view model that needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and include the properties you want to bind. Then in your page you simple set it as your data context. this.DataContext = myModel; Then you can simply change the properties on your model and they will reflect back in the UI. I suggest that you check out a MVVM tutorial